# RewriteRule to retain Query String

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule that I need to alter in order to have it retain the query string (if present) and pass it on:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://b.domain.com/subdir/ [R=301,NC]
```

Can you assist me with what I need to do to my RewriteRule to pass any existing query string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `QSA` (Query String Append) flag should do the trick.

[Mod_Rewrite Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 0):

The query string gets passed along by default, it should be showing up on your redirect. If you had a `?` in your rule's target (e.g. http://b.domain.com/subdir/?something ) then you'd need a `QSA` flag to have the incoming query string get appended.

If query strings are not getting appended to http://b.domain.com/subdir/ when you get redirected, something else may be stripping them.